# обновление данных из столбца массива

Tags: c++

```
void nr11(int A[101][101], int &n, int &m, int i,int j)
{
ofstream fin("date.in");
fin << n <<" "<< m<<endl;
int num;
cout <<" Введите значение столбца";
cin >>j;
for(int j = 1; j <= m; j++){
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
cin >>num;
A[i][j]=num;}}
 for(int j = 1; j <= m; j++){
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){

fin <<A[i][j]<<" ";}
fin<<endl;}}
```

Как изменить данные из столбца массива?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну судя по коду, вы хотите ввести новые значения в один столбец массива, а затем вывести весь массив в файл. Если это так, то тут многовато недочетов:

1. Переменная `j` передается по значению (как копия) в параметре функции, а потом сразу же вводится с консоли. Зачем тогда передавали?

```
void nr11(int A[101][101], int &n, int &m, int i,int j)
{
  ...
  cin >>j;
```

2. Переменные `m` и `n` (размеры массива) передаются по ссылкам, но нигде не изменяются. Зачем было передавать по ссылкам?

```
void nr11(int A[101][101], int &n, int &m, int i,int j)
{
  ...
  cin >>j;
```

3. В функцию передается копия массива. Если всё равно передаются размеры массива `m` и `n`, то проще передать по указателю. Но это просто замечание - допустим исходный массив не должен изменяться (хотя вряд ли - он записывается в файл) и тогда для простоты кода можно передать копию. Но всё равно передача больших блоков данных через стек - не самая хорошая практика.

```
void nr11(int A[101][101], int &n, int &m, int i,int j)
{
```

4. Вводится номер столбца с консоли и больше нигде не используется. Т.к в циклах объявляются новые переменные с именем `j`

```
cin >>j;
for(int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
```

5. Заполнение матрицы в двойном цикле - это полное заполнение всей матрицы, а не одного столбца

```
for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    { 
       cin >> num;
       A[i][j] = num;
    }
```

6. Поскольку заполнение матриц идет начиная с индекса 1, то цикл должен быть до `i<=n`
7. В конце функции в файл выводится транспонированная матрица - столбцы со строками поменяны местами. Но может так и надо?

Т.е. должно быть как-то так:

```
void
nr11 (int A[101][101], const int n, const int m)
{
  cout << n << " " << m << endl;
  int num = 1;
  cout << " Введите номер столбца ";
  cin >> num;
  cout << "Введите элемент \n";
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
      cout << "A[" << i <<"]["<< num << "]=";
      cin >> A[i][num];
    }
```

Comment: большое спасибо

Comment: Если ответ помог - нажмите галочку слева от ответа.